# Azure VM Failed not start stay on Updating mode

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I use azure vm, when vm is restart then failed to start vm error and stay on Updating mode, so I don't use azure recovery services.

Comment: Really hard to help, with no further information.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still experiencing the stuck in the **UPDATING** status, it's probably your VM's Disk ran out of space, what I did is I increased the size and it boot fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably more of a server fault question.

Couple of things you can try:

Completely stop the VM to stopped(deallocated) status, then boot it backup, if you have problem stop it from portal, use powershell cmdlet

Re-size the VM, normally would move it to another host and can jump off the problematic host

Delete the VM retain disks, create another VM from the disk.

There is also a good chance all above would fail. If you have a RTO, you might want to start preparing failover/recreate the machine in parallel.